# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.lang'; 'app' is not a package

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I have this file structure in my python project

```
|__src 
   |__main.py
   |__gen.py  
     |__app     
        |__ __init__.py
        |__ app.py
        |__ lang.py
```

#### Intention

I want to use the `Language` class from  sibling module `lang`.
So I tried with this import statement in `app.py`:

```
from app.lang import Language
```

#### Issue

But when I run `app.py` I get a ModuleNotFoundError error saying `'app' is not a package`:

[image]

Which doesn't make sense since app has `__init__.py`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: no screenshots. paste the text into your question

Comment: did you try just `from lang import Language` since they are in the same directory? or `from .lang import Language`

Comment: That seems to fix the problem of running the `app.py` but when I try to run `gen.py` which has `from app.app import Application` I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lang'`

Comment: Both files and *modules* (`app` and `lang`) are in the same directory and *package* (`app`), so you can import the module (without package-path prefix): `import lang`. See this tutorial [Python 3: Import Another Python File as a Module — Import a File in the Same Directory](https://csatlas.com/python-import-file-module/#import_a_file_in_the_same_directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both `app.py` and `lang.py` are in the same directory try to import like this :

```
from .lang import Language
```

or you can use `from app.lang import Language` from another file located outside app folder

Comment: That seems to fix the problem of running the `app.py` but when I try to run `gen.py` which has from app.app import Application I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lang'`

Comment: Yeah i noticed that i made a typo sorry .. you should use `from .lang import Language` .. i updated my answer and this should solve your issue

Comment: if the answer is correct plz mark it as accepted

Comment: Now when I run the `app.py` after that change I get this`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`